# Email Verification Page returned Page not found

Tags: support, jobs, email-verification

**How can I verify my account to ensure that hiring managers can reach me via email?**

I have got my profile on careers 2.0, They have sent me an email verification link , but it redirects me to Page not found.

So how can I verify my email? Is there any way to resend the verification mail?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like it was a bug on our end, but it's been fixed. Luckily for you we only verify e-mails for our own piece of mind. It won't keep you from using our site in any way. Just in case I sent you a new verification e-mail which should work. Good luck!